# HL1 input for MRTK v2.1

Tags: c#, mrtk

I am trying to find a configuration, or determine what additions I need to make to MRTK v2.1 to enable testing of HL1 in the 'Editor' work as it did with the prior workflow. Simplified, it is the ability to use Gaze and the mouse as we did prior to MRTK v2.

I have not found a way to map the left mouse button, in the profile, to behave as it does with the hand visible. With the hand visible pressing the left mouse enables manipulation. We simply need this with gaze as well. Note: Changing 'Hand Simulation' to Gestures does not produce the proper behavior it only makes the Gaze cursor persistent with no interaction.

I have asked this question in many places and it is often misunderstood so here is some background. We are continuing to deliver applications to clients that require stringent QA. They must be tested, as they have been while using the new MRTK. It is not reasonable to have our QA team use the articulated hands on a HL1 project as it introduces human error which is counterproductive to bug testing.

The needs are:
1. Have the cursor persistent in the Editor. (In the latest release, it disappears after using the hands via space bar.) This should be a toggle in our opinion. Yes, we know that you can press '1' to emulate select, but as mentioned in the above this is not acceptable for proper QA.
2. Have the left mouse button, without use of the hands, trigger 'Select' and 'Pinch'. I have written a service extension to handle the 'Select', but adding the pinch, as it is tied to the Hand articulation, has proven a challenge.

Proposed solutions so far: Change the 'Hand Simulation' mode to Gestures. Unfortunately, Gestures eliminates the ability to use the hands for HL2 testing and does not provide 'Select' or 'Pinch' behavior to the left mouse button. So it is either not working correctly or not the proper solution.

We do not see a reason why HL1 and HL2 cannot be tested in the editor at the same time. We are just missing the use of the left mouse button when the hands are not in use.

This is the Service extension I created for the left mouse button to send a 'Select' event. This will trigger an OnClick() event on an 'Intractable'. What it is missing the 'Pinch' ability to move or manipulate a 'Manipulation Handler' with the left mouse button as well.

```
[MixedRealityDataProvider(
        typeof(IMixedRealityInputSystem),
        (SupportedPlatforms)(-1), // All platforms supported by Unity
        "Unity Mouse Device Manager")]
    public class TharynMouseService : BaseInputDeviceManager, ITharynMouseService
    {
        private TharynMouseServiceProfile tharynMouseServiceProfile;

        public TharynMouseService(
            IMixedRealityServiceRegistrar registrar,
            IMixedRealityInputSystem inputSystem,
            string name,  
            uint priority,  
            BaseMixedRealityProfile profile) : base(registrar, inputSystem, name, priority, profile) 
        {
            tharynMouseServiceProfile = (TharynMouseServiceProfile)profile;
        }

        private IMixedRealityInputSource inputSource;
        private IMixedRealityInputSystem inputSystem;

        public override void Initialize()
        {
            // Do service initialization here.
            inputSystem = Service as IMixedRealityInputSystem;
            Debug.Log("inputSystem: " + inputSystem);

            inputSource = inputSystem.RequestNewGenericInputSource("Tharyn Mouse Service");
            Debug.Log("inputSource: " + inputSource);

            inputSystem.RaiseSourceDetected(inputSource);
        }

        public override void Update()
        {
            // Do service updates here.
            if (UnityEngine.Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
            {
                inputSystem.RaiseOnInputUp(inputSource, Handedness.None, tharynMouseServiceProfile.TapAction);
                Debug.Log("Down");
                Debug.Log("inputSystem: " + inputSystem);
                Debug.Log("inputSource: " + inputSource);
                Debug.Log("TapAction: " + tharynMouseServiceProfile.TapAction);
            }
        }
    }
```

Needs:

1. Trigger the same event that the '1' key does upon releasing the space bar to return the gaze cursor.
2. Extend the above service to include the 'Pinch' event/action so that object can be manipulated with Gaze and Mouse as it is with Hands.

Cheers and thanks in advance!

Tharyn

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve ability to simulate hand pinch, hand release events using just the mouse + cursor by creating a component that invoked OnInputDown and OnInputUp events to the MRTK Input System. You then need to attach this component to a game object in the scene.

The key code to simulate OnInputDown and OnInputUp events is the following:

```
public void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        InputSystem?.RaiseOnInputDown(
            InputSource,
            Handedness.Right,
            selectAction
            );
    }
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        InputSystem?.RaiseOnInputUp(
            InputSource,
            Handedness.Right,
            selectAction
            );
    }
}
```

Here is the full code for a component will raise input down and up events that will allow you to simulate pinch and drag + move using just the mouse:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input;
using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit;
using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Utilities;

public class SimulateSelectOnClick : MonoBehaviour
{
    private IMixedRealityInputSystem inputSystem = null;

    protected IMixedRealityInputSystem InputSystem
    {
        get
        {
            if (inputSystem == null)
            {
                MixedRealityServiceRegistry.TryGetService<IMixedRealityInputSystem>(out inputSystem);
            }
            return inputSystem;
        }
    }

    private IMixedRealityInputSource inputSource;
    private MixedRealityInputAction selectAction;

    private IMixedRealityInputSource InputSource
    {
        get
        {
            if (inputSource != null)
            {
                return inputSource;
            }
            inputSource = new BaseGenericInputSource("SimulateSelect",
               new IMixedRealityPointer[] { InputSystem.GazeProvider.GazePointer }, InputSourceType.Hand) ;
            return inputSource;
        }
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        var inputActions = MixedRealityToolkit.Instance.ActiveProfile.InputSystemProfile.InputActionsProfile.InputActions;
        selectAction = new MixedRealityInputAction();
        for (int i = 0; i < inputActions.Length; i++)
        {
            if (inputActions[i].Description.Equals("select", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                selectAction = inputActions[i];
            }
        }
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            InputSystem?.RaiseOnInputDown(
                InputSource,
                Handedness.Right,
                selectAction
                );
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            InputSystem?.RaiseOnInputUp(
                InputSource,
                Handedness.Right,
                selectAction
                );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, if this worked for you, can you please mark this as the correct answer, and upvote, so others see it in the future?

Comment: I have, I don't have enough points for it to be visible yet. :)